# POST 404 with Livewire + mcamara/laravel-localization

Tags: php, laravel, localization, middleware

This my Web Route

```
Route::group(
    [
        'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
        'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath']
    ], function(){

        Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {

            Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.index');


            Route::get('/adminlogin', 'AdminControllers\AdminLoginController@index')->name('adminlogin');
            Route::post('/adminPostLogin', 'AdminControllers\AdminLoginController@login')->name('adminPostLogin');
```

When I try to do something in Liveware this give like this error!!!

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

But when I commented middleware , Liveware is working, so what I should do pls give advise!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is working I just add this code inside Web

```
Route::post('livewire/message/{name}', '\Livewire\Controllers\HttpConnectionHandler');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure Livewire's update endpoint.

It's described in docs https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/installation#configuring-livewires-update-endpoint

Answer (score 1):

For livewire 3 add this code inside the localisation in web.php as:

```
Route::group(
        [
            'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
            'middleware' => ['localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath']
        ],
        function () {
            Livewire::setUpdateRoute(function ($handle) {
                return Route::post('/livewire/update', $handle);
            });
    
            Route::get('/', WebsiteHomepage::class)->name('website.homepage');
});
```